# Electronic switch IC for controlling power LED brightness

Tags: led-driver

I am looking for a small (~ Arduino Nano size) and power efficient way to control power LED brightness with one tactile switch.

The circuit would:

- long press - switch the LEDs to 30% brightness
- short press - switch LEDs to 60%, another press to switch to 100% and another press switch back to 30% and so on.
- long press - switch the circuit off

A nice feature would be to have led indicators for each power level (e.g. Red, Green, Blue, off), but not mandatory.

LEDs will be powered from a 5V battery and would draw 1.2A at full brightness. As power LEDs will need Constant Current to limit their brightness, the circuit will need to control the current to the LEDs.

**Option 1**

Use LM2596 DC-DC CC Power Supply Module, which already has a potentiometer to control the current.
Switch it on and off and control resistances of the potentiometer with a single button connected to IC. IC will:

- Switch power supply module off and on by a mosfet
- Control resistances of the power supply module with 3 fixed value resistors instead of the potentiometer.

**Questions**

- What ICs or already existing modules can be used to achieve that? Arduino with digital potentiometer like MCP4131 http://www.learningaboutelectronics.com/Articles/MCP4131-digital-potentiometer-circuit.php?
- Can resistance be controlled without digital potentiometer?
- Alternative options?

Comment: Generally the answer to that sort of thing would be a small MCU or maybe an Arduino nano or clone to switch a few logic outputs based on a pushbutton timing. But it's not really clear what you mean by "power level"- you might want to explain more about what  you are trying to do exactly.

Comment: What do you expect the circuit to do if the load demands more current than the control setpoint? You can't have constant current AND constant voltage. You *could* write the specification as "output current limit of 0.3 A, 0.6 A, 1.2 A at 5 V max." Are you just making an LED dimmer?

Comment: @SpehroPefhany I have amended the question. Basically I need to control LED brightness by controlling the current provided to them.

Comment: @Transistor yes, it is basically a LED dimmer with preset levels. I think power can be controlled e.g. by LM2596 DC-DC CC Power Supply Module, but I need to have a single button instead of potentiometer to control preset levels and to switch it on an off

Comment: You may be surprised how small the difference between 60% and 100% will be. You may want to target 10%, 30% and 100%. 3x more power with each step.  That will give you a night-light effect, evening light and full brightness.

Answer (score 1):

Using a microcontroller and PWM is the best approach. You can code the buttons as you wish and can modify the firmware much more easily than modifying a non-programmable circuit board. You'll be able to adjust the brightness levels exactly as required.

Since you're familiar with the Nano you can start there and develop your code. When the project is complete you could port it over to an ATtiny85 while using the Nano to program the Tiny.

[image]

*Figure 1. Wiring diagram for ATtiny85 programming using Nano from [Hao's blog](http://solosodium.github.io/2017-08-07-program-attint85-with-arduino-nano) which looks like it has enough detail to get you going.*

You can use an NPN transistor or logic-level MOSFET to switch the LEDs.

---

PWM (Pulse Width Modulation) is a technique where full power is applied to a device in pulses. The width of the pulses determines the average power and the frequency of the pulses is set high enough that the pulsing is not noticed. For LEDs and human vision a frequency above 50 Hz is good enough.

[image]

*Figure 2. PWM signal transitioning from high pulse width (75%) to low (25%) and back again. Note amplitude remains constant. Image source: [LEDnique](http://lednique.com).*

[image]

*Figure 3. A simple NPN switching circuit suitable for PWM control. Image source: [Driving LEDs on higher voltage](http://lednique.com/driving-leds-on-higher-voltage/).*

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but with PWM I can control the voltage and not the current, and because my  LEDs require constant current, I will have to connect them like:

Battery -> CC power supply like LM2596 -> mosfet like IRF520 -> LEDs.

And here with Arduino I will control the voltage output of Constant Current power supply, right?

Comment: See the update. With PWM you would set up the LEDs for full power and then switch the power as shown in Figure 2 and adjust the pulse width to control the brightness.